# Thymeleaf - How to apply two (or more) styles based on mutually exclusive conditions

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I need to have rows in a table alternate background color. I also need to have the text color in the rows be dependent on a value. How can I do this using Thymeleaf? Here's the code that I have:

```
<tr th:each="item, rowStat : ${items}" 
    th:style="${rowStat.odd} ? 'background: #f0f0f2;' : 'background: #ffffff;'"
    th:style="${item.getValue()} > 5 ? 'color: red;' : 'color: black;'">

                <td.... <!-- cols>

</tr>
```

This doesn't work though. Thymeleaf give a parsing error : `Attribute "th:style" was already specified for element "tr".`

**Update**

Meant to note that this an HTML email so I need to use inline styles.

Comment: Use 2 spans instead?

Comment: Did you tried: `th:style="(${rowStat.odd} ? 'background: #f0f0f2;' : 'background: #ffffff;')+(${item.getValue()} > 5 ? 'color: red;' : 'color: black;')"`

Comment: @benkuly +1 thanks. This works but I found another way that is supported by Thymeleaf and seems a bit cleaner especially as the number of conditional styles increase. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thymeleaf has a th:styleappend attribute that allows for multiple styles to be applied:

```
<tr th:each="item, rowStat : ${items}" 
    th:style="${rowStat.odd} ? 'background: #f0f0f2;' : 'background: #ffffff;'"
    th:styleappend="${item.getValue()} > 5 ? 'color: red;' : 'color: black;'">

                <td.... <!-- cols>

</tr>
```