# Thymeleaf - Interpolating a string into the conditional clause of a th:styleappend

Tags: thymeleaf

The following SO post describes how to conditionally append a literal CSS style attribute to the style attribute of an element.  (By literal, I mean coded directly into the TL template.)  The example given there is choosing which of two colors to use based on a predicate.

[Thymeleaf - How to apply two (or more) styles based on mutually exclusive conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044821/thymeleaf-how-to-apply-two-or-more-styles-based-on-mutually-exclusive-condit)

I'd like to go one step further and interpolate the conditionally appended style attribute value.  Is this possible?

Here are some attempts which didn't work:

```
<span th:styleappend="${option.color != null} ? 'background:${option.color}'">...</span>
```

Failed because interpolation doesn't happen in the single-quoted part, so '${option.color}' is output verbatim into the HTML.

```
<span th:styleappend="${option.color != null} ? 'background:'${option.color}">...</span>
```

Failed as this is not a valid TL expression.

```
<span th:styleappend="${option.color != null} ? background:${option.color}">...</span>
```

Failed because the : is taken as part of the tenary expression and not part of the output.

```
<span th:styleappend="${option.color == null} ? '' : 'background:'${option.color}}">...</span>
```

Hacky attempt.  Failed because not a valid expression.

I could hack around this using an `th:if`/`th:unless` and including (or not) the style in the two branches.  I'm looking to avoid this as this is not the only such attribute and I want to avoid an explosion of combinations.  Also the propriety of including the color attribute (a #rrggbb string) in the option is questionable, I know.  But the question is a general one however.

(Apologies in advance if this is a newbie question but no answer was forthcoming from multiple searches and I can't find it in the documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

Knowing about the + operator helps.  :-)

This works:

```
<span th:styleappend="${option.color} ? 'background: ' + ${option.color} : 'background: none'">...</span>
```

Comment: Glad you resolved it. There is a great overview of Thymeleaf syntax [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax), if you haven't seen it already.