# Thymeleaf multiple conditions, change background color

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Table cells in columns accountDTO.state and accountDTO.accountDTO should change background color, depending on the text value of accountDTO.state.
I've tried this:

[Thymeleaf - How to apply two (or more) styles based on mutually exclusive conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044821/thymeleaf-how-to-apply-two-or-more-styles-based-on-mutually-exclusive-condit)

and I've searched some more solutions, but everyone uses conditionals for two possible values, or in URL above there is multiple conditions. I have only one condition, but I have 9 possible values on that field. User selects a value for that field in a different web page. On this page, a list from database is shown.

Now I've tried with th:switch statement inside td tag but then I need to add span or div inside td, but in this case it doesn't work, cells are not colored.
I've searched for something like if/else/if structure or elif, but there is none it seems. And I can't repeat th:if in a single tag. I hope I can use th:switch but, why it doesn't work?

Below is just a shorter version switch, just some of the cases for this example, but I'll need nine cases in total.

```
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each = "accountDTO : ${listOfAccounts}">
                    <td th:text = "${accountDTO.accountDTO}"></td>
                    <td th:text = "${accountDTO.startBalance}"></td>
                    <td th:text = "${accountDTO.currentBalance}"></td>
                    <td th:text = "${accountDTO.state}" th:switch = "${accountDTO.state}"
                    ><span th:case = "${accountDTO.state} == 'OUT_OF_USE'" th:appendstyle = "'background: red'"></span>
                    <span th:case = "${accountDTO.state} == 'DEVICE'" th:appendstyle = "'background: green'"></span>
                    <span th:case = "${accountDTO.state} == 'LOCKED'" th:appendstyle = "'background: blue'"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td th:text = "${accountDTO.employee.employeeName}"></td>
                    <td><a th:href = "@{/editAccount/{id}(id=${accountDTO.idAccount})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id = "eBtn" th:data = "${accountDTO.idAccount}">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the variable as class to simplify the Thymeleaf and HTML. Then you can set the format consistently with your CSS. Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each = "accountDTO : ${listOfAccounts}">
        <td th:text = "${accountDTO.accountDTO}"></td>
        <td th:text = "${accountDTO.startBalance}"></td>
        <td th:text = "${accountDTO.currentBalance}"></td>
        <td th:text = "${accountDTO.state}" th:classappend = "${accountDTO.state}"></td>
        <td th:text = "${accountDTO.employee.employeeName}"></td>
        <td><a th:href = "@{/editAccount/{id}(id=${accountDTO.idAccount})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id = "eBtn" th:data = "${accountDTO.idAccount}">Edit</a></td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
```

Then look at something like this in your CSS:

```
td.OUT_OF_USE {
    background: red;
}
td.DEVICE {
    background: green;
}
td.LOCKED {
    background: blue;
}
```

Possibly useful for making similar output consistent on seperate pages.